# Setting a PHP script as a Windows Service

Tags: php, windows, windows-services

I need to set up a PHP script as a windows service.

I need it to run regardless of which user is logged in, and on system start up - so it sounds like a windows service is best, but am happy to hear other suggestions.

(This script runs continuously, it's not a "run every 5 mins" thing I could use the Scheduled Task Manager for.)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192 covers using the sc.exe program to install your service.

But from what I've read, I need to have a wrapper round the PHP script to accept the special commands from the windows service manager. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe the [Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657) (specifically srvany.exe) can help you here. MSDN: [How To Create A User-Defined Service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890/) and possibly [this hint for 2008 Server](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverMigration/thread/98a97aee-c62b-4683-94ab-3777899cf7de#2fafe061-3f0e-46cb-9ff6-843d4f04542a) should help you setup *any* executable as a service. (I've successfully used this on Windows 2003 Server, Windows 2008 Server and on Windows XP Professional [other Resource Kit, though])

You'd create a bat containing `php your-script.php`, wrap that with srvany.exe and voila, the script is started once the machine loads the services.

srvany.exe should handle those start/stop/restart calls you'd expect a daemon to execute. It would load your executable on start, kill the process on stop, do both on restart. So you don't have to worry about this part. You might want to check if a [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function) can help identify when your service process is killed.

You can even define dependencies to other services (say some database or some such).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\THENAMEOFYOURSERVICE]
"DependOnService"="DEPENDONTHIS"
```

replace `THENAMEOFYOURSERVICE` with the name you gave your service and `DEPENDONTHIS` with the name of the service to depend on (say "Postgres9.0" or something). Save that file to `dependency.reg` and load it with `regedit /s dependency.reg`. (Or doubleclick it in explorer…)

Comment: Hello - thanks for the detailed answer. I actually don't need to do this any more so wont be testing it at the moment, but this looks like the right path to try if anyone else does.

Comment: Although this is quite old, I'd like to point out an alternative to the very old srvany.exe (which does e.g. not react on a termination of the underlying php script): NSSM (non sucking server manager) its a compatible replacement to srvany.exe. See https://nssm.cc

Answer (score 3):

We used [FireDaemon](http://www.firedaemon.com/) for this task, it doesn't require wrapper scripts etc. Unfortunately it's not freeware.

Answer (score 2):

You can run php on command line by giving different parameters and also the script-file as parameter. If you add the whole line you need into the service configuration it should run. So you are also able to try the device before creating the service.
If the php-script is outside your web-route perhaps you should add the folder to the PATH-Variable of windows.

Answer (score 2):

I found this but haven't tried it myself. PHP actually comes with some functions to do this:
http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.win32service.php

Here are some examples:
http://uk.php.net/manual/en/win32service.examples.php

```
<?php
if ($argv[1] == 'run') {
  win32_start_service_ctrl_dispatcher('dummyphp');

  while (WIN32_SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP != win32_get_last_control_message()) {
    # do your work here.
    # try not to take up more than 30 seconds before going around the loop
    # again
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an unsupported PECL solution. You have to compile the .dll yourself.

See:  http://pecl.php.net/package/win32service

Comment: For me this should be the accepted answer, as it is a pure PHP solution, and the only one that can exchange messages with the SCM to manage the service state (notify the SCM that we are starting, catching messages when we have to pause / shut down, and so). Just don't forget to make a pause in the infinite loop, for example with `usleep`as @uldis sayed in his answer, to avoid eating 100% CPU.

Answer (score 1):

[NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc/) is also a solution, and then

```
nssm install PHP php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c C:\php\php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few days... i found this magnific option!

He build an .exe that recive the service options and works fine!

https://superuser.com/questions/628176/php-cgi-exe-as-a-windows-service/643676#643676

the command correct:

> sc create FOO binPath= "service.exe \"C:\php\php-cgi.exe -b
>   127.0.0.1:9000 -c C:\php\php.ini"\" type= own start= auto error= ignore DisplayName= "FOO php"

Comment: The OP asked "I need to set up a PHP script as a windows service." and you offered how to run php as a server. Two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Loop in shell.

1. In php loop add loop counter and exit after hour for restarting process.
2. memory usage controll
3. reconect to db each 100 seconds

Shell script do simple loop and each for iteration create new logfile

PHP and shell script:

```
    ini_set('memory_limit', '300M');
    $loopCnt = 0;
    while(true) {
        /**
         * Maximal time limit for loop execution
         */
        set_time_limit(10);
        $loopCnt ++;
        /**
         * each hour finishing
         */
        if($loopCnt > 60 * 60){
            exit;
        }
        usleep(self::SLEEP_MICROSECONDS);
        if ($loopCnt % 60 === 0) { //log every 60 seconds memory usage
            $this->out('memory usage: '.memory_get_usage());
            //reconnect DB to avoid timeouts and server gone away errors
            Yii::$app->db->close();
            Yii::$app->db->open();
        }
        if (memory_get_usage() > self::MEMORY_LIMIT) {
            $this->out('memory limit reached: '.self::MEMORY_LIMIT . ' actual:  ' . memory_get_usage() . ' exit');
            exit;
        }
        
        /**
        *  do work
        */

    }

}
```

// bat file

```
 set loopcount=1000000

 :loop

     echo Loop %DATE% %TIME% %loopcount%

     set t=%TIME: =0%

     php cwbouncer.php > C:\logs\cwbouncer_%DATE:~2,2%%DATE:~5,2%%DATE:~8,2%_%t:~0,2%%t:~3,2%%t:~6,2%.log

    set /a loopcount=loopcount-1

    if %loopcount%==0 goto exitloop

    goto loop

:exitloop
```