# execute a php script on windows from batch file in background?

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to run a php script from batch file, and I want to have it run in the background, so there will be no new PHP window, and also have the batch file window close immediately and not wait for the php script to end.
I've tried all of these:

1. `start php.exe myscript.php` - the batch file window close immediately, but a new php window opens and waits for the script to end
2. `start \B php.exe myscript.php` - no php window opens, but the batch file window stays open until the php script ends.
3. `php.exe myscript.php` - same behavior as with `start`

Is there a way I can achieve both - no php window and close the batch file console immediately?

Comment: Read this article/question. It will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952500/setting-a-php-script-as-a-windows-service

Comment: If PHP is a console program it needs a console to run. This is vbscript, you need something nonnative to hide a window. Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

msgbox FormatNumber(WshShell.Run("cmd /k dir c:\windows\*.*", 0, false))

Comment: @tonybd I don't understand your comment, what does vbscript has to do with my question? All I want is to start a php script from a batch file without having any window left open until the script is done.

Comment: Well look at the window then.What else can I do but repeat myself. It's crystal clear. If you don't write your own vbs script you cannot do what you want. Reread my original comments. 1. You MUST have a console for a console program. 2. There is no batch command to hide it. So you need to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
start /min myscript.php
```

let me know if it works for you.

Also you could have a look at this:

```
http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html
```

Comment: It is the same as without /min, only the php window is minimized, but it is still there...