# create the windows Service with php

Tags: php, windows-services

Create a windows service with phc-win or php/bcompiler?
I am using the phc-win and realized that compiles the php file using bcomplier. I wonder if it is possible to create a windows service with this tool.

Comment: Similar posting in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952500/setting-a-php-script-as-a-windows-service)

Comment: Probably is possible but better is to learn other languages besides php. Php has poor support to threads (maybe not at all), and never was designed for such purpose

Comment: Fortunately I managed to prepare a virtual machine with windows 7 and all the tools needed to compile php7. I got a sample code
Which allows you to create a windows service in C. At this point I am customizing the source code of php to create an executavé that can operate with a windows service. In future I intend to include bcompiler with this code. I do not want to find an immediate solution but make it possible to program with php through a windows service.