# Run Laravel queued jobs as windows service

Tags: laravel, queue

i want to know how to run Laravel artisan command:

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=3
```

as a service with windows so it will be executed automatically, and no need to run it in Command Prompt eash time.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a PHP script as a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952500/setting-a-php-script-as-a-windows-service)

Comment: i will give it a try, Thank you