# Running laravel queue:work as a background task in windows

Tags: php, laravel, windows, queue

I use supervisord to configure and run laravel queues as a background job on the linux machines. One of my customer can only use windows machine due to their company policy.

I want to run laravel queue as a background job on windows. I've came up with this solution below but I am not so sure if it is good way to do it.

```
forever -c php artisan queue:listen --tries=3
```

Anyone has tried it in production if yes how was experience with that or anyone has better solution with this situtation?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/supervisor-win/ is one solution. Another is to use the windows subsystem for linux and install supervisor as normal. There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952500/setting-a-php-script-as-a-windows-service) on how to run a PHP script as a windows service which mentions https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.win32service.php

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for your response, did you use any of them? how was your experience? thank you